# How to process a post request in the Vaadin application?

Tags: spring, servlets, vaadin

My task is that I need to process a post request in the Vaadin application
This is an [example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/push?hl=es&authuser=0#receiving-notifications) of a request that needs to be processed

I don't understand how in Vaadin I can get POST or GET requests
I also found documentation on [Creating a servlet 3.0 application](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/CreatingAServlet3.0Application) - not found for Vaadin v23

```
@Route("/")
@CssImport("./styles/shared-styles.css")
@CssImport(value = "./styles/vaadin-text-field-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-text-field")
@Log4j2
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

...

  public MainView() {
   
//    VaadinSession.getCurrent().addRequestHandler(
//        new RequestHandler() {
//          @Override
//          public boolean handleRequest(VaadinSession session,
//              VaadinRequest request,
//              VaadinResponse response)
//              throws IOException {
//            if ("/notifications".equals(request.getPathInfo())) {
//              // Generate a plain text document
//              response.setContentType("text/plain");
//              response.getWriter().append(
//                  "Here's some dynamically generated content.\n");
//              response.getWriter().format(Locale.ENGLISH,
//                  "Time: %Tc\n", new Date());
//
//              // Use shared session data
//              response.getWriter().format("Session data: %s\n",
//                  session.getAttribute("mydata"));
//
//              return true; // We wrote a response
//            } else
//              return false; // No response was written
//          }
//        });
  }


  @WebServlet(value = "/notifications", asyncSupported = true)
  public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    @Override
    protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
      super.servletInitialized();
      VaadinServlet servlet = getService().getServlet();
    }
  }
```

When calling http://localhost:8080/notifications
I get

```
Could not navigate to 'notifications'
```

With the help of the commented code, I manage to get into the request handler, but I doubt that this is the right way

```
//    VaadinSession.getCurrent().addRequestHandler(
    //        new RequestHandler() {
    //          @Override
    //          public boolean handleRequest(VaadinSession session,
    //              VaadinRequest request,
    //              VaadinResponse response)
    //              throws IOException {
    //            if ("/notifications".equals(request.getPathInfo())) {
    //              // Generate a plain text document
    //              response.setContentType("text/plain");
    //              response.getWriter().append(
    //                  "Here's some dynamically generated content.\n");
    //              response.getWriter().format(Locale.ENGLISH,
    //                  "Time: %Tc\n", new Date());
    //
    //              // Use shared session data
    //              response.getWriter().format("Session data: %s\n",
    //                  session.getAttribute("mydata"));
    //
    //              return true; // We wrote a response
    //            } else
    //              return false; // No response was written
    //          }
    //        });
```

Comment: You will need to add a route where you handle the POST/GET requests.
But I'm not sure this is what you realy wish.
Vaadin is more a kind of single page application, that a traditional php/jsp style coding

Answer (score 2):

> I also found documentation on Creating a servlet 3.0 application - not found for Vaadin v23

This should still work, so you would map the application to e.g.
http://localhost:8080/app/* so Vaadin would not interfere with http://localhost:8080/notifications

Comment: Yes, this approach should still work. *Vaadin Flow* is implemented as one Servlet, albeit a very large and very sophisticated Servlet. Your web app can have additional Servlets as well, independent of Vaadin Flow. The job of a [web container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) such as Tomcat or Jetty is to parse the incoming requests, then route them to the appropriate servlet. The Vaadin Flow servlet does not know or care if some requests are sent to other servlets.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the logic of Spring Boot (if your project hasn't already the dependencies, just include them in the pom.xml or by gradle)

Here is the code I use:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/user", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
String insert(@RequestBody User user) {
    mUserService.save(new User(user.getId(), user.getName(), user.getAge()));
    return "Data Inserted";
}
```

And here is an example how to post the data through postman:

[image]